# How to create Hive table with Azure WASB storage using account and account-key?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, hive, analytics, presto

Previously I was using AWS and reading the data using presto, now moved to Azure and want to create hive tables using blob storage for different accounts but I am unable to create it.
I  was creating hive tables for aws in below format.

```
CREATE TABLE hive.web.request_logs (
  request_time timestamp,
  url varchar,
  ip varchar,
  user_agent varchar
)
WITH (
  format = 'ORC',
  external_location = 's3a://key:secret-key@my-bucket/data/logs/'
)
```

I am trying below code for Azure:

```
CREATE TABLE hive.web.request_logs (
  request_time timestamp,
  url varchar,
  ip varchar,
  user_agent varchar
)
WITH (
  format = 'ORC',
  external_location = 'wasb://account:account-key.blob.core.windows.net@my-bucket/data/logs/'
)
```

I am expecting to create hive table for Azure blob storage for different account and account-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the configuration through Ambari to create external table on hive which is mapped to Azure Blob storage as follows:

Storage accounts to the existing clusters can be added via Ambari by following below steps

**Step 1:** Go to Ambari dashboard https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net/

**Step 2:** Navigate to HDFS -->Config -->Advanced, scroll down to Custom core-site

[image]

**Step 3**: Select Add Property and enter your storage account name and key in following manner

**HDFS >>Custom core-site**

Key => fs.azure.account.key.(storage_account).blob.core.windows.net

Value => (Storage Access Key)

[image]

**Step 4:** Navigate to HIVE => Config => Advanced, scroll down to Custom hive-env

[image]

**Step 5**: Select Add Property and enter your storage account name and key in following manner

**Hive** =>> **Custom hive-env**

Key => AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT

Value => (Storage Account name)

Key => AZURE_STORAGE_KEY

Value => (Storage Access Key)

[image]

**Step 6**: Restart services from Ambari

[image]

Hope this helps.